# How do I play Mountain on linux?

Tags: technical-issues, linux, mountain

I recently bought Mountain and I can't figure out how to run it on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit. I emailed the developer but they haven't responded in over a week. When I downloaded the game, it came with a mountain.x86 file but when I run it I get a missing library error and the missing library is not available in the package manager.

Comment: Might not be the answer you're looking for - but you can always download VMWare and install Windows on a virtual machine.. that's what I do for all my games that aren't compatible with Linux.

Comment: The game has a linux version which I downloaded but unfortunately it's not working for me

Comment: I don't know anything about the game, but I do know a thing or two about Unix and Ubuntu (12.)  If it were me, I would identify the packages required, then find a distribution source that provides the package.  Once you have enabled the source repository that you need, just apt-get or yum the package, and you're in business.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am right now playing Mountain on Ubuntu 14.10.

Mountain is now out on Steam, so I installed steam, paid $0.99 (again) and playing through steam is working great. I did install the proprietary nvidia drivers because I was getting some openGL error when I launched steam. Now the error is gone and I am playing Mountain.

Answer (score 4):

You need Mono installed, and if you are running 64-bit (most likely) you may also need to install the 32-bit versions of the graphics libraries that Mountain needs. Ubuntu has most of these libraries installed by default, but only in 64-bit. This is what I did to get going:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete libglu1-mesa:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxrandr2:i386
```

You should also make sure that you unpacked the zip with folders intact - there should be a `Mountain_Data/Mono` folder with `Mountain.x86` the only top level file.

Having said all that, I only get as far as drawing the sketches and the "LOADING" screen, then it crashes with a core dump.

Comment: I also managed to get it running on 64bit, but I did not install Mono, just the 32bit libraries. I've tried on 4 different computers now, and I also get the core dump crash on every one. I really want to check this out!